samtools fixmate threads for uncompressed bam data in pipeline
Samtools' documentation regarding duplicate marking suggests the following pipeline:
samtools collate -@ 4 -O -u example.bam | samtools fixmate -@ 4 -m -u - - | samtools sort -@ 4 -u - | samtools markdup -@ 4 - markdup.bam

With the following comment:

The -u option produces uncompressed output. Since the output is not being written to disk then size is unimportant and avoiding compress/decompress reduces the amount of work that needs doing. The -@ option turns on threading which can speed things up.

However, the documentation of samtools fixmate (*) says:

-@, --threads INT
Number of input/output compression threads to use in addition to main thread [0]. 


Since option -u is used upstream of fixmate and since fixmate also uses option -u, I expect fixmate to have no "input/output compression" to perform at all. Is providing threads to fixmate going to be of any help under these circumstances?
(*) http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools-fixmate.html
(samtools collate will read compressed input, samtools sort also uses threads for sorting, and samtools markdup will compress its output, therefore I expect some effect for option -@, --threads there.)

I think allowing samtools fixmate to use additional threads is unlikely to provide any performance benefit given that -u (for uncompressed output) eliminates the need for compression/decompression. I suspect that the main computational effort for samtools fixmate (i.e. fixing mate-pair information) will remain single-threaded. That said, the best way to verify any and all performance assumptions is to test and profile the pipeline. In my experience though, specifying -@ (for additional threads) is most beneficial when used with samtools sort where multi-threading can significantly improve performance. You may not even notice the impact of additional decompression or compression threads at the beginning and end of the pipeline.
